# Need help understanding some execution plans

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume a simple table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
[ID] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION,
[State] [tinyint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
)
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([ID])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NC_F_Media_StateNotDeleted] ON Table1 ([State]) WHERE ([State]<>(2))
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NC_F_Media_State] ON Table1 ([State]) WHERE ([State]=(0))
```

Values are inserted as follows:

```
250000 rows with State = 0
1000 rows with State = 5
```

And the following queries with their respective execution plans:

```
declare @mID int = 400000;
select State 
from Table1 
where (ID = @mID and State in (0, 1, 4, 5))
   or (@mID IS NULL and State in (0, 4))
```

[image]

Considering that `ID` is not null and therefore `@mid IS NULL` is mutually exclusive with `ID = @mID`, I rewrote the query as:

```
declare @mID int = 400000;
if @mID is null
begin
  select State 
  from Table1 
  where State in (0, 4)
end
else
begin
  select State 
  from Table1 
  where ID=@mID and State in (0, 1, 4, 5)
end
```

[image]

Questions:

1. Why the difference in execution plan between these two cases? Why is the nonclustered index only used in the second case?
2. Although the second case performs a seek vs. a scan for the case when `@mID` is null, does it really make any difference? The tooltip indicates that the performance hit is pretty much the same and I'm guessing this is due to the data being mostly `State = 0` rows.

Comment: There is difference between execution plan because first query has more filtered conditions than second query(inside if else block). SQL has to create execution plan which should work next time you execute the same query (May be next time you will pass NULL in parameter).

Comment: If you execute above two cases (first with @mID is not null and second with @mID is null) then you will find three execution plans in SQL cache (Three execution plans for all three `selects` of your cases).

Comment: @BhatiaAshish: I understand that there is a difference due to the if statement in the second case, but I'm wondering mode about why the non-clustered index is only activated in the second case and not in the first.

Comment: SQL Server uses Non-clustered index only for this query - `select State from Table1 where State in (0, 4)` because there is only one NC index which contains data for State in (0,4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when optimiser generates a plan for the query this plan must be valid for **any** possible values of parameters. Normally, the plan is cached and it is not re-generated when you run the same query again, so it must remain valid (produce correct result) even if you re-run the query with a different value of the parameter.

So, the plan for the first query must have such shape that would work for any value of the `@mID`, including NULL and not-NULL.

Index `IX_NC_F_Media_StateNotDeleted` can be used to find values for both parts of the `OR` expression, but either optimiser is not smart enough to build a plan that does two seeks of this index and then unions the result, or optimiser decided that such plan would be more expensive.

So, either optimiser is not capable of seeing *here* that `@mid IS NULL` is mutually exclusive with `ID = @mID`, or it decides that alternative would be more expensive.

The second query with explicit `IF` makes optimiser's choice obvious.

---

This type of query is called "catch-all" or "sink" query. I recommend to read an excellent article [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

In many cases it is appropriate to add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to your first query, like this:

```
declare @mID int = 400000;
select State 
from Table1 
where (ID = @mID and State in (0, 1, 4, 5))
   or (@mID IS NULL and State in (0, 4))
OPTION(RECOMPILE);

SET @mID = NULL;
select State 
from Table1 
where (ID = @mID and State in (0, 1, 4, 5))
   or (@mID IS NULL and State in (0, 4))
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Try to run these queries and examine their actual execution plans. You should see that the plan's shape changes according to the actual value of the parameter at the time of execution.

With `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` optimiser knows that the generated plan will not be cached as usual, so it takes the actual values of the parameters and inlines them as constants into the query. Once they are constants, *here*, the optimiser is able to see that `NULL IS NULL` is always true (or `400000 IS NULL` is always false) and collapses/simplifies the logic expression. Besides, optimiser is able to pick the best appropriate indexes in each case.

---

> Although the second case performs a seek vs. a scan for the case when
>   @mID is null, does it really make any difference? The tooltip
>   indicates that the performance hit is pretty much the same and I'm
>   guessing this is due to the data being mostly State = 0 rows.

In this case seeking an index is pretty much the same as scanning the whole table. Their sizes (in pages) are the same. If your table had a lot of rows with `State=2`, then filtered index would be more efficient, since it would contain less pages than the main table.

Comment: This is the most thorough answer and seems to align with my observations.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is not using the index in the first query because the variable is been used as part of the criteria (@mID IS NULL and State in (0, 4)) in this case the @mID IS NULL because this is not a column cant be included in an index and this is the reason sql can't activate the index. In the second query with the if you are removing this problem and the index is activated.

In the second section of the if because you have the clustered index is faster for sql to find this specific record and then evaluate if the state have any of those values to show the result.

Something additional out of the question scope, after some testing I have found something interesting. When the value of the states became more balanced lets say have values for every possible option form 1 to 5 the execution plan change and the first query became as good as the option using the if.

```
declare @mID int = 400000;
select State 
from Table1 
where (ID = @mID and State in (0, 1, 4, 5))
   or (@mID IS NULL and State in (0, 4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of the issue :
In the first case SQL Server has to come up with a query plan that would be a good enough plan to satisfy whether the @mid value has been passed or not.

The two conditions in the first query would benefit from different indexes, but then would logically need joining the result set as it is an OR condition. So it decides on a plan that would satisfy both conditions in a single scan on the clustered index.

In the second case, the issue is eliminated and thus SQL server can use different indexes on the separate queries